# Parallel processing- Foraech and for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, foreach, parallel-processing

I want to produce a matrix which I put produce process below. But it tooks so much time.
Is there any other way to get same result quicker with using foreach and parallel processing?

"""

```
library("foreach")
library("doParallel")
lambdas=seq(0.01,7, by = 0.01)

cl <- makeCluster(2) # create a cluster with 2 cores
registerDoParallel(cl) # register the cluster
nlambdas <-foreach(i = 1:1, .inorder=FALSE ,.combine = 'cbind', .multicombine=TRUE, .packages = "quantreg") %dopar% {
  first<-rep()
  second<-rep()
  third<-rep()
  fourth<-rep()
  for (m in 1:700) {
    for (j in 1:700) {
      for (n in 1:700) {
        for (k in 1:700) {
          first<-rbind(first,lambdas[m])
          second<-rbind(second,lambdas[j])
          third<-rbind(third,lambdas[n])
          fourth<-rbind(fourth,lambdas[k])
        }      
      }
    }
  }
  lambda_total<-cbind(first,second,third,fourth)
}

stopCluster(cl)
```

"""

Comment: `rbind` copies each object and appends to it. This is one of the least efficient ways of going about this. At this point, I would suggest reading [The R inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: It looks like your code is very similar to `as.matrix(expand.grid(lambdas, lambdas, lambdas, lambdas))[,4:1]`, so maybe that is a good place to start. However the output of your example would be a matrix with 240,100,000,000 rows and four columns which may well be beyond the capacity of your computer to create. You might need to take a step back and think of a different way to approach the problem

Comment: Thank you both of you.

Comment: @Miff I used your recommendation, thank you again. I work on 64gb Ram pc and I am able to produce just 200^4 x 4  matrix.    I set "lambdas"  as  `lambdas=seq(0.01,2, by = 0.01)
res=as.matrix(expand.grid(lambdas,lambdas,lambdas,lambdas))[,4:1]`. When I try for lambdas=seq(0.01,3, by = 0.01) It gives an error. So is there any way to produce this with splitting?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need parallel processing, you just need an algorithm with less than (O**4) complexity and a slow operation to compose this matrix.

The same matrix may easily be constructed by repeatedly sorting four vectors. In your case, however, with 700**4= 2.4e+11 elements, this might take some time.

I illustrate the algorithm with only 7 different values in the vector `lambdas` (and 2401 elements in total).

```
nsteps = 7
lambdas = seq(0.01,7,(7/nsteps))

h = rep(lambdas,nsteps**3)
i = rep(lambdas,nsteps**3)
j = rep(lambdas,nsteps**3)
k = rep(lambdas,nsteps**3)

ordering = order(k)

k = k[ordering]
k = k[ordering]
k = k[ordering]
k = k[ordering]

j = j[ordering]
j = j[ordering]
j = j[ordering]

i = i[ordering]
i = i[ordering]

h = h[ordering]

lambdas.total = cbind(first=h,second=i,third=j,fourth=k)
```

If your memory is large enough to cope with ordering a vector with length>10**10, you can do this with 700 steps for lambda in no time.
No need for any for loops.

Comment: Dear Martin, my memory is not large enough. Is there a way that I can do it separately and combine it later to give the same order?

Comment: Unlikely. But there may be a way to accomplish what you want to do without creating this monstrous matrix.

Comment: Thank you again. I try to find lambda values that satisfy some conditions. Whwn I have lambdas.total, I am going to run codes below. `mylist_095<-rep()
cl <- makeCluster(8)
registerDoParallel(cl)
res05 <-foreach(i = 1:240100000000, .inorder=FALSE ,.combine = 'cbind', .multicombine=TRUE, .packages = "quantreg") %dopar% {
              
  f <-rqss(Y~qss(x1,lambda = lambdas.total[i,1])+qss(x2,lambda = lambdas.total[i,2]) +qss(x3,lambda = lambdas.total[i,3])+qss(x4,lambda = lambdas.total[i,4]), tau=0.05,data=data)
  sf<-summary(f) 
  #if condition here
    mylist_005<-(f$lambdas)`

Comment: So I guess there is no other way.

Comment: Of course there is. You could employ a grid search for the optimal lambda values by first using the `seq(0.1,7,0.1)`, which has only 70 values (2'400'000) rows, that should be manageable. When you find a region that is promising, you can narrow down the lambas to that region. Alternatively, you could use a genetic algorithm that finds the optimal values for all four parameters. Or you could not do it in memory but create a file with 2.4e+11 lines and scan line by line. Don't give up yet. But don't just use brute force for such a complex problem.

Comment: This will be helpful, thank you so  much again. Best.